# Pandas GroupBy freq='M' and put into Plotly

Tags: pandas, plotly

I am doing a groupby (freq='M') but I than want to put the results into Plotly.  (I am brand new to Plotly or Plotly Express.)

This works fine:

```
g = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).sum()


date

2020-11-30       80.00
2020-12-31    13102.75
2021-01-31     4630.00
2021-02-28      460.00
2021-03-31    13980.11
```

I then want to create a chart which would be something like this.

```
fig = px.line(g, x = "date", y = "amounts", labels= {'x': 'date', 'y': 'values'} )
```

Because it is a Groupby I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'columns'
```

I know data changes after something like a Groupby - so how can I overcome this to use in Ploty?

thank you

Comment: try adding `as_index=False` to the groupby so that it does not set the date column as index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try resetting the index

```
g = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).sum().reset_index()
fig = px.line(g, x="date", y="amounts", labels={'x':'date', 'y':'values'} )
```